# Symfony: How to upload multiple files

Tags: php, symfony

I'm pretty new to Symfony and I'm trying to upload multiple files (images) using Symfony Forms and the Vichuploader-Bundle.

My TestObjectType looks like this, which should hold a collection of Image objects:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('images', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => new ImageFormType(),
        ));
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => TestObject::class
    ));
}
```

ImageFormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
            ));
    }
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Image::class
        ));
    }
```

Part of the controller code:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
        $form = $this->createForm(TestObjectType::class, $testObject);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {  
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($testObject);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute("home");
        }
}
```

I get the following error while submitting:
`Neither the property "imageFile" nor one of the methods "getImageFile()", "imageFile()", "isImageFile()", "hasImageFile()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "TestBundle\Entity\TestObject".`

My TestObject does not have an `imageFile` property, however my Image object does. So what is missing here? Why is the `imageFile` property of the Image object not used? I've already read [How to Upload Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html) and [CollectionType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) but it did not helped much.

*EDIT*

Maybe a snippet of my entities could be useful:

TestObject

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TestBundle\Entity\Image", mappedBy="testObject")
 */
private $images;
```

Image

```
    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
     *
     * @var File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $imageName;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestBundle\Entity\TestObject", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="test_object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $testObject;
```

Comment: Do you have getters and setters defined for imageFile and imageName properties in the Image entity?

Comment: Yes, every property has getters and setters defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution: Symfony`s cache make me angry! A simple

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

did the trick! Argh, that took me hours!